# How to make a keyboard shortcut that's usable from behind the KDE lockscreen?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, lock-screen

I have a CLI command that I can use to turn toggle the power to my monitor for my media PC. I'd like to be able to use this even when the PC is locked. I'm okay installing a daemon like `xbindkeys`, but am not sure how to forward specific keyboard shortcuts when the computer is locked.

Comment: You have to modify the source.